# How can i transfer Array to table in TodayExtansion (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, today-extension

How can i transfer array to table in Today Extansion (Swift)

I'm new to this and nothing happens

---

**In main app i have a table with data**

**In Today Extansion i have a table (in which the data should be displayed)**

**its work with TEXT but not work with ARRAY**

---

```
var myData: [String] = []
```

**MainVC.swift**

```
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.Name1") {
        userDefaults.set("Test12345" as AnyObject, forKey: "key3")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

**TodayExtVC.swift**

In ViewDidLoad:

```
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.Name1") {
                let value2 = userDefaults.string(forKey: "key3")
                print("\(value2)") 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set in MainVC.swift

```
    let array = ["horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"]

    userDefaults.set(array, forKey: "key3")
```

get  in TodayExtVC.swift

```
     let myarray = userDefaults.stringArray(forKey: "key3") ?? [String]()
```

Comment: Displayed so - []

Comment: as you stored it empty

Comment: you need to create an app group first in order to share data betwwen the app and the extesion. after that it almost the same as save and get data from the user settings .                                                                                     for example (objective-c)  : NSUserDefaults *shared = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.yougroup"];
[shared setObject:object forKey:@"yourkey"];
[shared synchronize];

Comment: @nevgauker he already has created the group but the problem is in saving and reading an array

Comment: alright  , maybe this will help ? :  let savedArray = defaults.object(forKey: "SavedArray") as? [String] ?? [String]()